# How to solve `rails generate ...` commands hanging?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, rubygems, code-generation

Just installed and successfully add `gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"` to gemfile and bundled successfully; `Bundle complete!` with twitter-bootstrap-rails 3.2.0. Then trying, as instructed by gem documentation, to; `rails generate bootstrap:install static` but the command just hangs.

I checked whether other `rails generate` commands work and indeed they hang also. Can anyone help me diagnose and fix the issue? I'm unsure where to look to try to find out what the problem is under the hood. I'm running `Rails 4.2.1` and `Ruby 2.2.1`, here is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'devise'

gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'

  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do

  gem 'capybara'

  gem 'pry-rails'

  gem 'shoulda-matchers', github: 'thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers'

end
```

Answer (score 2):

After lots of searching [this link](http://www.dixis.com/?p=754) suggested spring was the issue and to try a `spring stop`. Upon running this and calling `generate` again everything worked just fine. Thank you `spring stop`, now to go and learn some more about what `spring` actually is and does!